# 'Merging' open shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a lot of overlapping paths that I need to unite. The red square needs to be removed on all of the paths.

[image]

However, the unite tool won't work due to the paths just being lines and not closed shapes. I really need something that will do the trick since I have hundreds of these squares. What can I use instead? Thanks!

Comment: So, why can't you just use closed shapes to make the pattern?  Then Pathfinder Unite would work just fine.

Comment: @BillyKerr the paths that they would have to end at were curved. It would have been really hard to go about that (by the methods I know of, anyways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Select all the lines

• **Shape Builder Tool** > holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete drag over the lines that has to be removed

[image]

Comment: This just made all the paths into one compound path and didn't remove the inside of the squares.

Comment: Ok, the question is not that clear in this case, what squares should remain and which ones should disappear? To release a compound shape: Menu Object > Compound Path > Release. By the way, there are not any square at the image.

Comment: The red area needs to be removed. https://imgur.com/a/S0BcPWq

Comment: @HoneyPhantomhive Although there would have been a easier workflow that would have eliminated this entire step. Is theimage what you actually wanted to do or a proxy of what you wanted to do?